# Unable to run nicks pallet on Macbook M1 Pro

Tags: substrate-node-template, polkadot-local

I am having an issue when running `nicks-pallet` on my computer. I followed [the set up process of a substrate node](https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/work-with-pallets/add-a-pallet/) but still can't run a successful `cargo check -p node-template-runtime` or `cargo build` but I am getting the error

```
error: failed to select a version for `syn`.
    ... required by package `frame-support-procedural v4.0.0-dev (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git?tag=monthly-2022-07#279593d8)`
    ... which satisfies git dependency `frame-support-procedural` of package `frame-support v4.0.0-dev (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git?tag=monthly-2022-07#279593d8)`
    ... which satisfies git dependency `frame-support` of package `frame-system v4.0.0-dev (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git?tag=monthly-2022-07#279593d8)`
    ... which satisfies git dependency `frame-system` of package `pallet-nicks v4.0.0-dev (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git?tag=monthly-2022-07#279593d8)`
    ... which satisfies git dependency `pallet-nicks` of package `node-template-runtime v4.0.0-dev (substrate-node-template-test/runtime)`
    ... which satisfies path dependency `node-template-runtime` (locked to 4.0.0-dev) of package `node-template v4.0.0-dev (substrate-node-template-test/node)`
versions that meet the requirements `^1.0.98` are: 1.0.98

all possible versions conflict with previously selected packages.

  previously selected package `syn v1.0.95`
    ... which satisfies dependency `syn = "^1.0.84"` (locked to 1.0.95) of package `async-trait v0.1.53`
    ... which satisfies dependency `async-trait = "^0.1"` (locked to 0.1.53) of package `jsonrpsee-core v0.13.1`
    ... which satisfies dependency `jsonrpsee-core = "^0.13.1"` (locked to 0.13.1) of package `jsonrpsee v0.13.1`
    ... which satisfies dependency `jsonrpsee = "^0.13.0"` (locked to 0.13.1) of package `node-template v4.0.0-dev (substrate-node-template-test/node)`

failed to select a version for `syn` which could resolve this conflict
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: I would recommend cloning https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-node-template and running `cargo build --release` again and see if it works.

Comment: This is exactly what I am using, it builds without `nicks-pallet` but I can't build it with after I attempt to add it according to [this](https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/work-with-pallets/add-a-pallet/).

Comment: Hi, can you try using the same `branch` as the others crates to pull the `pallet-nicks`. Something like this 

pallet-nicks = { version = "4.0.0-dev", default-features = false, git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", branch = "polkadot-v0.9.25" }